# Aren't parenthesis supposed to be optional when a hash is the last argument?

Tags: ruby, parsing, syntax

I am sure that this is usually the case, but I'm not sure why it's not working here:

Here's the code

```
  let(:stubbed_object_list) { [OpenStruct.new key: "foo"] }
```

And here's the error:

```
SyntaxError: ...filepath...: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ']'
```

I can fix the code by instead using `OpenStruct.new(key: "foo")` but I don't see why this is necessary.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the array brackets, because this works fine:

```
  let(:stubbed_object_list) { OpenStruct.new key: "foo" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It becomes ambiguous if you add another key-value pair:

```
[OpenStruct.new key: "foo", other: "bar"]
```

`other: "bar"` could be another array element:

```
[OpenStruct.new(key: "foo"), other: "bar"]
#=> [#<OpenStruct key="foo">, {:other=>"bar"}]
```

or another argument:

```
[OpenStruct.new(key: "foo", other: "bar")]
#=> [#<OpenStruct key="foo", other="bar">]
```